# Error in Datepicker on Android

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm trying to open a dialog for picking a date on Android. Here is my code :

```
 et_date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_date);

    et_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");



        }
    });
```

And I have this class :

```
 public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        }
    }
```

And I get this error :

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.EditText.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I still get the same error.

Comment: Actually you should pass view object . Its a fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is:

**et_date is null**. You are tried to set listener for null object. That's why, It gives this error. Double check with your layout xml.

For debugging, just add null check and set lisetner to "et_date" as below

```
if (ed_date != null)
{
 // print log here to find this as error. 
// set listener here.. 
}
```

**Update from your comments:**

Add below code in your fragment. Move the variable "ed_date" to your fragment, it should not be in Activity.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ed_date = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ed_date);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make it not null? Thanks.

Comment: this answer is perfect

Comment: @jason Just check your activity layout with this id "et_date". If it's not there, assign the id with corresponding text view.

Comment: Actually `et_date` is in a fragment which is in that activity, I call `et_date `from activity. Does this cause problem? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, should I add onclick event handler to fragment as well?

Comment: Ya Sure. If you are adding a code for event action which is on your fragment, event listener should be in the fragment. That' will make your code more readable.

Comment: One last question : After I pick date, how can I pass that date value to that `EditText` namely `et_date`

Comment: you can directly write the code into this method `public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day)` as `et_date.setText(......)`...